# how to use array to store list of contacts

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning `angular.js`. I am trying to create an app with gmail chat box like implementation. So as a first step I created an implementation where you can create groups and add members from the available contacts array.

First I will show all group available if you click on add group I will show you list of contacts from where you can click on the particular contact I will take the index and add it to new array and then push it into a my contact array.

Here is part of my code

```
app.factory('contactfactory', function (){   
    var factory = {};

    factory.contacts = [
        {email:"vicky-1"},
        {email:"vicky2"},
        {email:"vicky3"},
        {email:"vicky4"},
        {email:"vicky5"},
        {email:"vicky6"},
        {email:"vicky7"},
        {email:"vicky8"},
        {email:"vicky9"},
        {email:"vicky10"},
        {email:"vicky11"},
        {email:"vicky12"},
        {email:"vicky13"},
        {email:"vicky14"},
        {email:"vicky15"},
        {email:"vicky16"},
        {email:"vicky17"},
        {email:"vicky18"}
    ];

    factory.myGroups = [{
        groupName: "Avangers",
        members: ["vicky-1","vicky2","vicky3"]
    }];

    factory.getGroups = function (){
        return factory.myGroups;
    };


    factory.getContacts = function (){
        return factory.contacts;
    };

    factory.newcontact = [];
    factory.newGroup = {};

    factory.createMember = function (index) {
        console.log(factory.contacts[index].email);
        factory.newcontact.push(factory.contacts[index].email);
        console.log("inside createmem()" + factory.newcontact);
    };

    factory.createGroup = function (groupName) {
        factory.newGroup.groupName = groupName;
        factory.newGroup.members = factory.newcontact;

        factory.myGroups.push(factory.newGroup);
        console.log(factory.newGroup);
        factory.newcontact = [];
    };

    return factory;
});
```

the error i get is

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to
>   specify unique keys. Repeater: group in groups, Duplicate key:
>   object:019

this my code in jsfiddle
 http://jsfiddle.net/vickyvignesh/E6NzM/

Comment: [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat) must have unique values to iterate over.

Comment: your fiddle is broken. consider using plnkr.co to show angular code